# Facebook APP - There is no WhatsApp when adding product to my APP

Tags: whatsapp, facebook-apps

I'm trying to create a Facebook APP to use the WhatsApp Business Cloud API. Following this guide:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/whatsapp/cloud-api/get-started

It says: "From the App Dashboard, click on the app you would like to connect to WhatsApp. Scroll down to find the "WhatsApp" product and click Set up."

But there is no WhatsApp product at all. There are other products, but only WhatsApp is missing.

Does anyone know why it is like this?

Attached the image of the whole window. [Screen Capture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lu1ut.png)

Comment: It will not show if you have already set up before, so look at the left menu at the bottom you will see the WhatsApp menu under the products section.

Comment: Thanks for reply, but there is nothing in the products section in left menu.

Comment: try to create a new app, I am not sure there might be some issue in the old app.

Comment: Thanks. I've created other APPs but all the same. And one of my colleague have met the same problem as me. But another colleague in India can see the WhatsApp product. Maybe this is Geo related? Is it because the Facebook account of Mine and my first colleague are in China. so we cannot see the WhatsApp product?

Comment: I don't know if you can create a [personal support request](https://developers.facebook.com/support/) on Facebook.

Comment: same issue here, any solution?

Answer (score 0):

Is your app a business type? The third point mentions "Create a Meta App: Go to developers.facebook.com > My Apps > Create App. Select the "Business" type and follow the prompts on your screen"

Comment: Yes, my APP is Business type.

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a Business Account, here you handle all your business apps
2. Create another business  app and select the first business app as your meta Business Account
3. Now you can select Whatsapp as product

   (i'm not sure if you have to verfity the first business app)